# Move an object a percentage every frame ("Zeno's Arrow" style)

Tags: infinity, fractions, continued-fractions

Every frame, I want an object to move a percentage of the way from where it is to its target. A value of `1` means it reaches the target in exactly one frame, and a value of `0.5` means in one frame it has gone `0.5` way to its target, the next frame `0.75`, etc.

[image: diagram]
*(diagram stolen from [this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1162896/55164))*

Since we are moving at fixed frames (not infinitesimals), barring floating-point precision, the object will never reach the target.

The code for this is easy. Here it is in C# pseudocode:

```
void onEveryFrame() {
    currentX += (targetX - currentX) * speed;
}
```

The problem is, **How do I make this frame-rate independent**?

So someone running at 30 frames per second will see the object move at about the same speed as someone running at 60 frames per second?

Comment: I apologize for taking a detour from the "abstractness" of math, to ask for a real world solution. It doesn't have to be perfect, just close enough that the slope is similar.

Answer (score 1):

Just divide your desired speed by the framerate:

`currentX += (targetX - currentX) * speed / framerate;`

You may want to increase the speed constant to compensate for this division. For example, if you've tested this on 30 FPS before, now write a 30 times higher speed. The division by the framerate will cancel this factor out. If you are doing 60 FPS, you will be doing it twice as often, but half as fast. And so on.

Comment: That's the naiive answer, which I had tried originally. Let's take one extreme: _You want the object to move at 1.0 "speed". At one frame per second it reaches its target instantly. At two frames per second, it's infinite time to get there, and very slow!_

Comment: It's exactly the math for the value to "compensate for this division" that I'm trying to find (and the reason I went to Mathmatics SE instead of just plain [_StackOverflow_](http://stackoverflow.com/) or [_GameDev SE_](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)).

Comment: You test with *some* framerate, and multiply the originals speed by that. I'm afraid I don't understand what you are trying to do otherwise, you will need to provide some more detail. Preferably with some mathematical rigour. @IQAndreas

Comment: @IQAndreas I am fairly certain that this is actually the standard solution for this issue.

Comment: @Carser Definitely the standard, I keep seeing other people using it all the time! Too bad it's dead wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Since your trajectory is so well defined, you can calculate the position for any time $t$.  Simply start a timer when your trajectory starts, then every time you want to refresh (it doesn't even have to be a constant frame rate), you can update the position $x$ using
$$
x = 1 - \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^t
$$

If you are starting at some non-zero position $x_0$, then your position at time $t$ is just $x_0$ plus the above:
$$
x = x_0 + 1 - \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^t
$$
or if you like

```
x = startX + 1 - (1 / 2^t)
```

You shouldn't need to multiply by "speed," especially since the speed here is not constant, but exponentially decreasing as the trajectory approaches startX+1

Comment: So, if I wanted to replace those constants with variables, would it look something like this? `x = startX + (targetX - startX) * ( 1 - speed^time );`

Comment: @IQAndreas I added more to the answer above.

Comment: I guess my terminology needs adjusting. By _"speed"_, I meant something more like _"decay rate"_; user can increase the value of this variable to get closer to the target more quickly (up to a value of `1`, in which case they would be instantly at their target destination). So I still want that `1/2` constant to be an adjustable variable.

Comment: Awww, got it.  Then yes just replace the 1/2 with something from between 0 and 1.

Comment: This is definitely in the right direction! But, I'm trying to plot this, and it seems to be opposite of what I want: https://graphsketch.com/?eqn1_color=1&eqn1_eqn=1-(1%2F2)%5Ex&eqn2_color=2&eqn2_eqn=1-(1)%5Ex&eqn3_color=3&eqn3_eqn=1-(1%2F4)%5Ex&eqn4_color=4&eqn4_eqn=1-(.99)%5Ex&eqn5_color=5&eqn5_eqn=&eqn6_color=6&eqn6_eqn=&x_min=-.5&x_max=5.5&y_min=-.1&y_max=1.1&x_tick=.5&y_tick=.1&x_label_freq=2&y_label_freq=1&do_grid=0&do_grid=1&bold_labeled_lines=0&bold_labeled_lines=1&line_width=4&image_w=850&image_h=525

Comment: Is it enough just calculating the "decay rate" as `(1-rate)^t`, or will that give me a different function? EDIT: Yep, that fixed it! It _seems_ I'm getting the correct distance per frame: https://graphsketch.com/?eqn1_color=1&eqn1_eqn=1-(1-1%2F2)%5Ex&eqn2_color=2&eqn2_eqn=1-(1-1)%5Ex&eqn3_color=3&eqn3_eqn=1-(1-1%2F4)%5Ex&eqn4_color=4&eqn4_eqn=1-(1-.99)%5Ex&eqn5_color=5&eqn5_eqn=&eqn6_color=6&eqn6_eqn=&x_min=-.5&x_max=5.5&y_min=-.1&y_max=1.1&x_tick=.5&y_tick=.1&x_label_freq=2&y_label_freq=1&do_grid=0&do_grid=1&bold_labeled_lines=0&bold_labeled_lines=1&line_width=4&image_w=850&image_h=525

Comment: Through some fiddling, I got the equation I needed! Should I add it as an answer, or give an edit suggestion to yours?

Comment: I think you may find you are still using the same equation I gave you.  For example, looking at your graphsketch I see you have 1-(1-1/2)^2 but that's the same as 1-(1/2)^2 as in the answer above.

Comment: For the value `1/2`, it is the same, yes. But for other values it is the opposite. I also have more code that includes the distance to the target, etc.

Comment: Opposite of what?  It seems you are using the equation but just preferring to think of your rate as .9 instead of .1 for example.  That's fine, but it's the same equation, just a matter of what you want to call the quantity you are raising to the exponent.

Comment: Opposite of what I picture in my head, of course. ;) I added an answer that contained all the variables I needed, as well as the actual code. The final equation looks a bit messy, but as far as I can tell, that's as far as I can simplify it, right? You have been an immense help! Your math skills get rusty when you haven't used them for a decade. :P

Answer (score 0):

[The answer by Carser](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1903660/55164) gave me almost everything I needed. The following function returns a value from 0 (at he starting position) to 1 (at the target), with $t$ representing the current number of seconds elapsed.

$$
x = 1 - \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^t
$$

There are few things we need to add for the equation to work in our code:

$$
x = x_0 + \Delta x * \left( 1 - \left(1-rate \right)^t \right)
$$

In the equation, $x_0$ is our starting value, $\Delta x$ is the total distance to the target (in our case `targetX - startX`), and $rate$ is what I called *speed* in my original answer, renamed for clarity.

The $rate$ variable determines how close to the target we get each second. A value of `0.5` means every second we are half as close to the target as the previous second. A value of `1` means we are "instantly teleported" to our target in that second, and a value of `0` means we never reach the target.

And for some actual code, the following should be valid in C#, and fully framerate independent (even supports reversing time, though, you might get some funny results if you go into negative time):

```
x = startX + (targetX - startX) * (1 - Math.Pow(1-rate, currentTime - startTime));
```